# Making varnish log time_firstbyte and handling

Tags: varnish, varnish-4

I am trying to log `time_firstbyte` and `handling` in a file via `varnishncsa`.

My `/etc/init.d/varnishncsa` looks like below:-

```
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

NAME=varnishncsa
DESC="HTTP accelerator log deamon"
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
DAEMON=/usr/bin/$NAME
PIDFILE=/run/$NAME/$NAME.pid
LOGFILE=/var/log/varnish/varnishncsa.log
USER=root
LOG_FORMAT="%t %r %s %b %{Varnish:time_firstbyte}x %{Varnish:handling}x"
#VARNISHNCSA_ENABLED=1
DAEMON_OPTS="-a -w ${LOGFILE} -D -P ${PIDFILE} -F '${LOG_FORMAT}'"

# Include defaults if available
if [ -f /etc/default/$NAME ] ; then
        . /etc/default/$NAME
fi

# If unset, or set to "0" or "no", exit
if [ -z "${VARNISHNCSA_ENABLED}" ] || \
   [ "${VARNISHNCSA_ENABLED}" = "0" ] || \
   [ "${VARNISHNCSA_ENABLED}" = "no" ]; then
  exit 0;
fi

test -x $DAEMON || exit 0

start_varnishncsa() {
    output=$(/bin/tempfile -s.varnish)
    log_daemon_msg "Starting $DESC" "$NAME"
    create_pid_directory
    if start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --pidfile ${PIDFILE} \
        --chuid $USER --exec ${DAEMON} -- ${DAEMON_OPTS} \
        > ${output} 2>&1; then
        log_end_msg 0
    else
        log_end_msg 1
        cat $output
exit 1
    fi
    rm $output
}

stop_varnishncsa(){
    log_daemon_msg "Stopping $DESC" "$NAME"
    if start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE \
        --retry 10 --exec $DAEMON; then
        log_end_msg 0
    else
        log_end_msg 1
    fi
}

reload_varnishncsa(){
    log_daemon_msg "Reloading $DESC" "$NAME"
    if kill -HUP $(cat $PIDFILE) >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        log_end_msg 0
    else
        log_end_msg 1
        exit 1
    fi
}

status_varnishncsa(){
    status_of_proc -p "${PIDFILE}" "${DAEMON}" "${NAME}"
    exit $?
}

create_pid_directory() {
    install -o $USER -g $USER -d $(dirname $PIDFILE)
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start_varnishncsa
        ;;
    stop)
        stop_varnishncsa
        ;;
    reload)
        reload_varnishncsa
        ;;
    status)
        status_varnishncsa
        ;;
    restart|force-reload)
        $0 stop
        $0 start
        ;;
    *)
        log_success_msg "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|force-reload|reload}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac
```

My `/etc/default/varnishncsa` looks like below:-

```
 VARNISHNCSA_ENABLED=1
```

But while trying to do restart `varnishncsa` it is failing.

I am on ubuntu 12.04 with varnish 4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [link](http://giantdorks.org/alain/workaround-for-broken-varnishncsa-logging-due-to-shell-mishandling-of-spaces-in-log_format-variables/) updating my `/etc/init.d/varnishncsa` as below solved the issue:-

```
LOG_FORMAT="%h|%u|%{%Y-%m-%d}t|%{%H:%M:%S}t|%{%z}t|%m|%{Host}i|%U|%q|%s|%b|%{Referer}i|%{User-agent}i|%{Varnish:time_firstbyte}x|%T|%D|%{Varnish:handling}x|%{X-FE-Varnish-Obj-TTL}o|%{X-FE-Varnish-Backend}o|%{X-FE-Varnish-Obj-Stat}o"
DAEMON_OPTS="-a -w ${LOGFILE} -D -P ${PIDFILE} -F '${LOG_FORMAT}'"
```

Answer (score 0):

The %T format specifier can be tricky if you are also using ntp. Because the response time can be very small - you may end up with negative values in your log file if the clock skew changes in the middle of the request. If you are post-processing your varnishncsa logs you may end up with results you were not expecting.